# How to provide my valid SSL certificate to my reactjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ssl, ssl-certificate

I just finished a ReactJS app for my website and is ready to production mode. I have not figure out how get it working under https mode. This app was developed with create-react-app in a local environment, and now this app is deployed to a Red Hat Enterprise Linux server. I have Googled, but unfortunately there is not much information available about how to do this.

I already set `HTTPS=true` in package.json and react-scripts with no result because this process due to the fact that I used a self-signed certificate while developing the app; I need to figure out how to use my new, valid certificate now.

Comment: You can host your app on GitHub for example using your production or build files.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the SSL certificate is the job of the server, not the react application.

Comment: thanks for your answer! you right, it's a server task to do! my valid certificate is ok for apache and works well with https on port 80 and 443 automatically redirect, the point is that my react app is a parallel aplication running on a port 3000 like http://www.myReactApp.com:3000 and does not work with https, how to config the server for ssl valid certificate for a ReactJS application? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I have found a solution!!! I followed these steps to define mi valid certificate: first I have installed react-app-rewired with: npm install react-app-rewired --save-dev then I have added this to the file config-overrides.js

Comment: I have found a solution!!! I followed these steps to define mi valid certificate: 
take a look in more detail here: 

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2759#issuecomment-332940060 and https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired